# How to group MenuItems in WPF ContextMenu without nesting them?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have MenuItems whose `Visibility` properties are controlled by a converter. Most often the MenuItems have the same visibility logic (same converter, same parameters). To avoid retyping I want to virtually group them together to only set the visibility once.

I know I could achieve that by nesting MenuItems. Is there another way?

Comment: Bind them to one propery. Once property changed, they all get updated.

Comment: Good Point! Actually, I hoped to have a XAML-only solution

Comment: XAML only would be a attached property that doesnt know about ViewModel. Bind MenuItems to attached depedency property if you dont want to use a property from ViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too clear on what you want to do but I suspect a style will be handy. I'll give an example. Here I create a button in a grid that has a context menu. In the Button's resources I create a style (that's not named) for MenuItems. In the style you can specify how the visibilty should behave by replacing the Binding I created.

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Testing" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding SomeBinding, Converter=SomeConverter}"/>
                </Style>
            </Button.Resources>
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="1"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="2"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="3"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="4"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: That would change the visibility of all MenuItems. I just want to change MenuItems that share their visibility state.

Comment: Fair enough. How about you apply that style individually instead of having the style affect all of the MenuItems? Or am I still misinterpreting the problem?

Comment: I think that's the way to go if I want to avoid properties. I updated your code snippet. Thanks